# how can I intercept a window.location.href change and change what happens next?

Tags: cypress, href

I have a `window.location.href` change happening in a button `onClick` event on login, it sends the user to a different subdomain where they will then be redirected to a third party OAuth login flow

I want to just handle user login myself within cypress with mock values when the button is clicked, but how can I prevent the page from hitting my real endpoint?

`cy.intercept` doesn't seem to be working for this sort of thing, and `cy.on` doesn't seem like it's the right option either

###### example button

```js
const goToUrl = () => {
  let url = `${process.env.API}/oauth`
  if (props.siteEntry) url += `?redirect=${props.siteEntry.includes('/authorize') ? process.env.BACKBONE : props.siteEntry}`
  window.location.href = url
}

// ...

return (
  <RaisedButton
    onClick={() => goToUrl()}
  />
)
```

Comment: Do you know if it is using window.location.replace method?

Comment: added sample from my codebase

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stub out the `window.location` as per variation of [Deal with window.location.replace](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowlocationreplace).

It's a bit of a monkey-patch on your app, but there is no way to "properly" stub `window.location` methods or properties because it's protected.

```js
cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  win.__location = {
    href: null
  }
})

cy.intercept('GET', '/', (req) => {
  req.continue(res => {
    res.body = res.body.replaceAll(
      'window.location.href', 'window.__location.href')
  })
}).as('index')

cy.visit('/')       // during page load, window.location is stubbed

cy.wait('@index')
```